# Why is the css still applied when it is deleted?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

deleted css file in my rails project entirely.

cleared browser cache restarted server.

the css is still applied. How can this be if my assets/style sheet folder is empty???????

Comment: Try CTRL+F5, and/or a different browser.

Comment: Or incognito mode. (to answer your question, it can't be.  Its cached somewhere, or another copy of the css exists somewhere else).

Comment: Or may be its loading third party stylesheets inside `vendor` folder

Answer (score 0):

You probably still have a local copy of compiled assets. Try running `rake assets:clobber` from the command line.